# Docusaurus: Add file headers to many files quickly

Tags: file, markdown, docusaurus

[Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/en/) requires Markdown documents to have [headers](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/doc-markdown.html) with some meta information, e.g.

```
---
id: doc1
title: My Document
sidebar_label: Document
---
```

I have 100 existing `.md` files that I want to use with Docusaurus.

**Question:** What's the best/fastest way to insert such a header into each file?

Bonus points if it automatically uses the file name (without extension) as the `id`, and any existing L1 or L2 header (without the `#`/`##` prefix from line 1) as the `title`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bash script/Node script to do this. This is not within the scope of Docusaurus.